# What is the purpose of SQLite or SQL Server integration with Bonobo?

Tags: sql-server, git, sqlite, bonobo

I downloaded the Bonobo Git Server and installed it both locally (Windows 7) and on a Server (Windows 2012). I initially used the default setup, to learn about it. The default username and password worked, as did creating test users.

I then removed all instances of SQLite and swapped them to SQL Server. At the same time, I also enabled Windows Authentication with AD Member Services. After creating a new catalog, bonobogit, on a SQL Server instance I can see tables related to Repos, Teams, Users, and Roles were created. However, none of these appear to be used. Instead, there appears to be corresponding directories and files under the ~/App_Data directory.

What is the purpose of SQL Server or SQLite for a Bonobo Git server? Is it possible the combination of settings I have make them moot?

Thank you in advance for any guidance or advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the purpose of SQL Server or SQLite for a Bonobo Git server?

The sql server is used to store all your data like stash does.
Git itself doesn't require but usually remote server use it for several reasons:

- Backups - Store the data in Db as well for backups
- User management
- Clustering
- Performance

and more.

---

Basically its much **faster to read** data from database then from HD, the lookup is much faster, backup are easier, recovery and sociability again are much easier to maintenance.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then what gets stored at these files level is also stored at the database level? Is this in a timer, is there an additional setting, it does it just happen out of there box?

Comment: its for the internal implementation of the server, basically nothing to do with git itself just the managing of the serve, and you are cirrect